# Joomla htaccess rewrite exception for custom index.php issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I am trying to make an exception to the default htaccess from Joomla 1.6.3 for having a friendly url for my own php scripts.

The idea is that the following already working url:
www.mysite.com/wrx/system/index.html?parameter1=AE23HtySght34P
can externally be called like this, but also shows as:
www.mysite.com/wrx/system/AE23HtySght34P/

The rule i placed in the htaccess is working, but reverts it to showing the php with the parameter...

Any help would be appreciated.

Simon

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteRule ^wrx/system/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /wrx/system/index.php?id_parameter1=$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this one just after `RewriteEngine on`, so it's the first being evaluated.

```
RewriteRule /wrx/system/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /wrx/system/index.php?id_parameter1=$1 [L]
```

- ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ catches all (1+) chars (not only digits) till end of url
- [L] = last rule (for this evaluation, the rewritten url will be evaluated against the rules again)

Comment: Thanks Guido :) I just edited my question at the same time you answered.
So it works indeed like you said (found that already), but it's not exactly what i want... 
If possible i want to keep the URL showing like:
www.mysite.com/wrx/system/AE23HtySght34P/

Comment: @Simon remove the R=301 from the options, which involves an http 301 redirect (a new request is made)